# How to show all data using looping in Json Array

Tags: android, loops, android-recyclerview

How to Loop to show all cuisine data (New American, Japanese, Asia). In `RestaurantRVAdapter`, I used like this -
`List<Restaurant> restaurant; // There is a data in restaurant holder.tv_cuisine.setText(restaurant.getCuisine().get(0).getCuisineName());`

It only shows New American because I use `.get(0).getCuisineName()`

```
[
  {...},
  {...},
  {...},
  {...},
  {
    "restaurant_id": "41",
    "restaurant_logo": "52ee9f67ce39f62d9c0b1538ca26646f.jpg",
    "restaurant_name": "Shwe Lar Food Restaurant",
    "street_address": "Napier Road",
    "phone_no": "09940255323430",
    "rating": "4.5",
    "cuisine": [
      {
        "cuisine_name": "New American"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Japanese"
      },
      {
        "cuisine_name": "Asia"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: what / how do you want your list of cuisines to appear?

Comment: Yes. I want list of cuisines to show.

Comment: post your code so that i can suggest you a answer.

Comment: @StevenLin but _how_? what shape do you expect it to take?

Answer (score 0):

In your RecyclerView Adapter update your code like this.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Restaurant rest = restaurant.get(position);
    holder.tv_cuisine.setText(rest.getCuisineName());
}
```

Comment: No, there is no .getCuisineName() in Restaurant List. Restaurant List < Cuisine List < CuisineName

Comment: Post your `Restaurant` model class.

Answer (score 0):

First you get jsonArray then used fori lool to get all json object then you can get exat data, like as

```
JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("cuisine");
  List<JSONObject> postList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonPost = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        postList.add(jsonPost);
                    }
                    mAdapter.updateList(postList, mStockstype);
```

in Adapter you make a method like

```
  public void updateList(List<JSONObject> list, String type) {
    mDataList.clear();
    mDataList.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in adapter you get you data

```
   JSONObject object = mDataList.get(position);
    String name = object.optString("cuisine_name");
```

Comment: paste this code in your Class like Fragment or Activity, where you are setting adapter  to listView

Comment: share your adapter

Comment: Sir, where is obj come from?

Comment: Basically Obj is jsonObject that come from your jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Build comma separated text for Cuisines,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Restaurant rest = restaurant.get(position);
    List<Cuisine> cuisineList = rest.getCuisine();
    // Build comma separated text for Cuisines
    String strCuisine = "";
    for(i=0; i<cuisineList.size(); i++) {
        strCuisine.concat(cuisineList.get(i).getCuisineName());
        strCuisine.concat(",");
    }
    holder.tv_cuisine.setText(strCuisine);
}
```

Comment: Hi, it says can't resolve method getAdapterPosition(); And then concat; in String can't be applied to com.wp.model.Cuisine `cuisineList.get(i)`

Comment: Simply use `position`. Look at edit. However you may user `holder.getAdapterPosition` too.

Comment: Thank, but how to solve concat String to Model (cuisineList.get(i))

Comment: Post your `Restaurant` class. So that I can look up into the code. I've edited the code.

Comment: I use String.valueOf(cuisineList.get(i)). It is OK. But Can't resolve symbol strCuisine :D

Comment: No no no.. By using `cuisineList.get(i)` you are getting just and object of model. you need to get `cuisineName` as string. Look at my edited code.

Comment: @StevenLin, Try to debug your code. M sure you'll find your bug :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Restaurant rest = restaurant.get(position); // get the specific restaurent
    List<Cuisine> cuisineList = rest.getCuisine();  // list to carry cuisineList
    String cuisineString = ""; //string to carrying cuisines
    for(int i=0; i<cuisineList.size(); i++) {
        cuisineString.concat(cuisineList.get(i));
        cuisineString.concat(",");
    }
    holder.tv_cuisine.setText(strCuisine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should like this,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Restaurant rest = restaurant.get(position); // get the specific restaurent
    List<Cuisine> cuisineList = rest.getCuisine();  // list to carry cuisineList
    String cuisineString = ""; //string to carrying cuisines
    for(int i=0; i<cuisineList.size(); i++) {
        cuisineString.concat(cuisineList.get(i).getCuisineName());
        cuisineString.concat(",");
    }
    cuisineString = cuisineString.substring(0, cuisineString.length() - 1);// Removes last ,
    holder.tv_cuisine.setText(cuisineString);
}
```